# Cordova file plugin returns non existed path

Tags: cordova

I want to get the path to the folder where some files will be downloaded from my server. This code looks like:

```js
// Get path to cache and download
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, entry => {
   console.log('download to', entry);
   // My download function
   fileDownload('some string url', entry.toUrl());
}, err => {
   console.log('error', err);
});

// Download function
function fileDownload(url, fileURL) {
  let fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  let uri = encodeURI(url);

  fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      fileURL,
      entry => {
          console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
      },
      error => {
         console.log("download error", error);
      },
      true
  );

  return fileTransfer;
}
```

If `config.xml` contains lines

```xml
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal"/>
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files, cache, sdcard, cache-external, files-external"/>
```

this races error FileError.code = 5 (ENCODING_ERR)

If used `Compatibility`

```xml
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
```

this returns entry path `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<my-app-id>/cache` but this path does not exist in my Nexus 5 and the code with download races error 1 (FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR)

```
FileTransferError {...}
body: null
code: 1
exception: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<my-app-id>/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)"
http_status: 200
source: "http://my.domain.com/photos/photo.jpg"
target: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<my-app-id>/cache/"
```

I see in ES File Manager correct path as `/sdcard/Android/data/<my-app-id>/cache` and think the problem is that.

Any ideas how to get correct path?

Comment: Try using cordova.file.externalDataDirectory instead as cache directory may have permission issues.Chekc out this working sample - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: Unfortunately I see Alert dialog onGetDirectoryFail after click Download button.

Comment: did you made necessary changes as mentioned in readme?

Comment: Yes, I install all plugins and set url to image file, for sample http://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg

Comment: Could you try downloading some pdf instead of images to isolate the issue? Also in the existing sample, opener plugin code's mime type is set to 'application/pdf' which have to be changed for images. But atleast your download is successful?

Comment: http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.ptf Still mistaken.

The phone on Android 6.0.1.

Comment: I tried different files, like https://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/images/d/d3/Test.pdf